# Related fields on model?

Tags: django, django-models

There is a model **ElectoralTable**

```
class ElectoralTable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    country_owner = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city_owner = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    country_owner = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='country')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('country_owner', 'name', )
```

How can I to select a city related to a country. Rigth now I receive every city on Model City but I want only to receive the cities related wiht country owner

Comment: Can you add city and country model...

Comment: Of course the post was edited

Comment: Well, where do you want to select cities related to country owner.??? Please, explain more with examples bro.

Comment: In ElectoralTable model I want to do something like this I select a country 'Argentina'  in the field country_owner then receive only the cities of Argetina but the field city_owner is given me all the cities of the world

Comment: how are you getting city_owner? WHere?

Comment: I'm just using django admin site. I want to avoid to save a city who doesn't belong to the right country

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214511/discussion-between-biplove-lamichhane-and-nicolas-rondon).

Answer (score 1):

Well I found one solution to prevent save a city who doesn't belong to country it was to overwrite the clean method

```
  def clean(self):

        city = City.objects.filter(country_owner__name=self.city_owner)
        city_names = []
        for item in city:
            city_names.append(item.name)
        if not str(self.city_owner)  in city_names:
            raise ValidationError(_('The city doesn't belong to the country'))
```